# SalesForce Chatter Rest API - Can not set CreatedDate

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I want to set the **createdDate** for a new feed-element (via SalesForce Rest API).

I tried to do this:

```
{ 
    "body" : {
      "messageSegments" : [
         {
            "type" : "Text",
            "text" : "When should we meet for release planning? "
         }]
       },
    "feedElementType" : "FeedItem",
    "subjectId" : "0060Y00000XYZXYZ",
    "createdDate ": "2016-10-27T08:01:56.000Z"
}
```

But I get this error message:

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR",
        "message": "Unrecognized field \"createdDate \" at [line:-1, column:-1]"
    }
]
```

I read that I can set the createdDate via API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_feed_element.htm), but I don't find a example or a way to do this.

Also I tried to set the createdDate in a update request, but the same result.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Those are audit fields, isn't it? Why do you want to update the created date?

Comment: because we want to transfer the notes of our old system to salesforce. We want to set the createdDate like the original createdDate. And you're right, that is an audit field

Comment: Sorry to comment on an old thread, but wanted to add the info for anyone else coming here from google.  You need to add this permission via permission set: `Insert System Field Values for Chatter Feeds`